# How to replace phone number with Xs?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, replace

I use the following regex to find phone number in the text (number could be with or without country code, with different separators etc.):

```
phonePattern = re.compile(".*?\d?(\(?\d{3}\D{0,3}\d{3}\D{0,3}\d{4}).*?", re.S)
result = phonePattern.search(text)
```

Now I would like to replace digits with Xs. For ex., if I found phone like `1 (123) 123-4567`, then it should be replaced with `1 (XXX) XXX-XXXX` in the text. How can I do it?

Comment: Are you only looking for US phone numbers? Because you're not going to remove most numbers from other countries.

Comment: @Ben, I am looking for any country phone numbers (see `\d?` for country code in my regex), `1 (123) 123-4567` is just an example.

Comment: Most countries have a 2 digit country code (some 3). Even if you're looking at countries that have a 1 digit code you're not going to get everything. For instance the standard international phone format for the UK is `+44 02D DDDD DDDD` or `+44 0DDDD DDD DDD` (the first 0 is optional). You don't match a single thing. France is `+33 DD DD DD ...` you don't get that either. You've assumed a US format and that every country has the same amount of numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `phonePattern.sub()` call, but drop the `.*?` start and end (those are not needed here anyway):

```
phonePattern = re.compile("\d?(\(?\d{3}\D{0,3}\d{3}\D{0,3}\d{4})")
result = phonePattern.sub(lambda m: re.sub('\d', 'X', m.group(1)), text)
```

Without the `.*?` patterns the `re.S` flag can be dropped too. The leading `\d?` is rather redundant here; without a space between that digit and the `(` character allowed it certainly doesn't match your sample pattern.

For every match found, a `lambda` function is called to provide a replacement, which simply takes the grouped text (`m.group(1)`) and replaces all digits with `X` characters.

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> text = 'Here is a phone number: 1 (123) 123-4567'
>>> phonePattern = re.compile("\d?(\(?\d{3}\D{0,3}\d{3}\D{0,3}\d{4})", re.S)
>>> phonePattern.sub(lambda m: re.sub('\d', 'X', m.group(1)), text)
'Here is a phone number: 1 (XXX) XXX-XXXX'
```

Comment: `re.S` becomes redundant, as well, and last, the `\d?` at the start doesn't seem to do anything, at least not if there's no space after it.

Comment: @Jerry: indeed, it can be dropped as well here.

Comment: Thanks, @MartijnPieters. The demo looses country code (with another example `1(123)1234567`), but I think it is OK in my case.

Comment: @LA_: That's because the leading `\d` in the pattern (which should allow for whitespace after it) is not grouped and re-used in the replacement value. Consider putting a group around that too (and update the `m.group(1)` call to `m.group(2)`, then prepend `m.group(1)` to the `re.sub('\d', 'X', ...)` result.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
phone = "1 (123) 123-4567"
replaced_phone = phone[0] + re.sub("\d", "X", phone[1:]) # 1 (XXX) XXX-XXXX
```